# Using Scons to compile a C++ project under Cygwin - cl error

Tags: build, cygwin, scons

I am trying to compile a C++ project using Visual Studio 2010 Express by running a `scons.bat` inside a Cygwin shell. I am in the folder that I am supposed to run Scons in, but I am getting a cl error. Here is my output:

```
The Citadel EE@TheCitadelEE-PC /c/JTS/PracticeCode/PingComponent_120
$ /c/Python27/Scripts/scons.bat
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: Building for Windows...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
cl /FoC:\JTS\jaustoolset-2.2.1   \GUI\templates\Common\Build\InternalEvents\InternalEventHandler.obj /c C:\JTS\jaustoolset-2.2.1\GUI\templates\Common\src\InternalEvents\InternalEventHandler.cpp /TP /nologo -DWIN32 -DWINDOWS /MD -EHsc -D_CRT_SE CURE_NO_DEPRECATE -DTIXML_USE_STL /I. /Iinclude /IC:\JTS\jaustoolset-2.2.1\GUI\templates\Common\include                                                                        cl is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
scons: [C:\JTS\jaustoolset-2.2.1     \GUI\templates\Common\Build\InternalEvents\InternalEventHandler.obj] Error 1             
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I have tried running vcvarsall.bat under the DOS command prompt to set the environment variables, but that's not working so far.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in case anybody else is having the same issues I had, here is what I did to solve the problem:

I opened up the command prompt for Visual Studio (VS), went to the directory where my C++ files were located, and ran scons.bat (also I added the path to scons.bat so I can just type 'scons.bat' instead of the entire pathname). This automatically set certain environment variables so I could build the C++ files with VS using the command line ('cl'). After doing this, I was able to build my project successfully with SCons. Also, I did not use Cygwin, and I don't any more for my current project. I found I can do everything I need to do with the Windows command prompt.